# Why function is executed first in console.log?

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

Have a look at this snippet:

```js
let first = 1;

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

console.log(first, second()); // 2 1
```

I expect it to print `1 2` in order instead of `2 1`. Why function `second` is executed first?
I observe if both the arguments to `console.log` are functions, the order in which they are passed is preserved(see below example)

```js
function first() {
  console.log(1);
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

console.log(first(), second()); // 1 2
```

Please explain this behavior with relevant resources.

Comment: Since `second` is followed by `()`, you are calling it inline and its output will be passed as input to `console.log`

Comment: "Please explain this behavior with relevant resources": fwiw this sounds like a homework instruction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All arguments in an argument list are evaluated *before* the function containing the argument list is called. So

```
someFn(first(), second());
```

will *always* call `first`, then call `second` (along with any other arguments), until it comes up with intermediate values like

```
someFn(firstResultExpression, secondResultExpression);
```

at which point `someFn` will be called with those (now resolved) expressions.

In this case, `someFn` happens to be `console.log`. So if `first()` and `second()` log anything themselves, those logs will always appear first, before the last `someFn` starts doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

The post is a bit misleading because the comment suggests the output is `2 1`.

```
console.log(first, second()); // 2 1
```

But what is actually output is:

```
2
1 undefined
```

We get `2` output first, because `console.log(first, second())`
calls `second()` and this outputs `2` in console.log.

**Note that the function `second()` returns nothing.**
If a return value is omitted from a function, **undefined** is returned instead.

**Then** `console.log(first, undefined)` is evaluated and we get the output

```
1 undefined
```

**Note that if second() returned a value** (say 3 for example):

```
let first = 1;
function second() {
   console.log(2);
   return 3;
} 
console.log(first, second());
```

Then the output is

```
2
1 3
```